# How to use Jinja (in Flask) for complex reports?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

As much as I like to use Jinja (combined with Flask) I really wonder how to deal with very complex reports I need to display on a page.

Here are just a few things I want to display

1. Make averages and sums for columns
2. Different rows must have different colors or values (based on the rest of the rows and columns - so simple CSS rules would be a pain)
3. Show charts (ex: pie charts, etc) either as JPG/PNG or JavaScript generated.

So what is the good practice in Jinja world to deal with complex reports?

Comment: Have a look at the [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/) library.  Generate charts and graphs here, store as HTML, embed in the web page, then serve with Flask.